# ClassCastException when persisting enum via Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, persistence, classcastexception

I've now wasted several hours trying to get this to work, but Hibernate still keeps me wondering what's going on there inside.
Here's what I want to do:
Simply persist a `List` of `enum`s via `@Enumerated` which looks like this:

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@ElementCollection(targetClass=Role.class)
@JoinTable(name = "userroles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"))
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private List<Role> roles;
```

My `enum` class:

```
public enum Role implements Serializable {
    employee("Mitarbeiter"),
    manager("Geschäftsleitung"),
    stationleader("Stationsleitung"),
    administration("Verwaltung"),
    accountant("Buchhaltung");
@Transient
private String description;

private Role()
{

}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

private Role(String desc) {
    this.description = desc;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return description;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}   
}
```

The error I'm encountering occurs at a simple `persist()` of the class which is holding the `List`. And it's root cause is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum
at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeSet(EnumType.java:118) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeSet(CustomType.java:155) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.writeElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:811) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1201) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:58) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:264) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:190) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1081) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:315) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:104) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
```

How could I resolve this? There doesn't seem to be any known bugs of this and I just found non-answered threads in several forums. I also tried `EnumType.STRING` and leaving some of the annotations, without effect though :/
**EDIT:**
I also tried to just use a raw `enum` with standard constructor and no fields, nothing but the values. So the error must not lie in my enum-pojo.
**EDIT2:**
My problem lied a bit elsewhere. ([JSF and type safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433250/jsf-and-type-safety)). However I will accept the answer how pushed me in the right direction :)

Comment: Try converting your enum names to uppercase. If that doesn't help, set the logger level to TRACE and post the log here.

Comment: @MarlonBernardes Converting to uppercase didn't change a thing. It also doesn't seem to work setting `Logger log = Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate.SQL");
        log.setLevel(Level.TRACE);` as I don't see more log entrys than before. (1 Info)

Comment: Use "org.hibernate.type" instead of "org.hibernate.SQL". Don't set it manually, it must be configured before application startup (eg.: log4j.properties -> log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE)

Comment: Well, still there's only one thing getting printed and that's `INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements` within those exceptions. It's hibernate 4.2.1Final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your Enum have custom attributes you have some options:

1. Create your custom type  (UserType) as follows:
   https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UserTypeforpersistingaTypesafeEnumerationwithaVARCHARcolumn
2. Create your Enum property as a transiente and use a String getter
   and setter to populate.

Comment: I already tried that. I wanted to explain that in the section below. But now I see I wrote ORDINAL there, too :/
Actually `String` was the first thing I tried.

Comment: What exception you got when you used String?

Comment: Wouldn't 3 be the case when I tested it with a raw `enum`(no properties)? Because that's what I already did and that sadly didn't work out. The 1st would probably the best solution, but it seems so overcomplicated.

Comment: With a raw enum it must work. If didn't we will need to check your database structure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29570/discussion-between-zhedar-and-br-araujo)